# iOS OpenEars not recognizing accurate sound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, speech-recognition, openears

I want to implement an speech recognition feature in my iPhone app by research i came to know about OpenEars library and i downloaded that and got a sample project along with it i got a sample project,when i run it and if i say "hello" it is returning as "you said LEFT",i tried for many word combinations but i'm getting only Left,Right,Down,Forward & etc certain set of responses. Is this a bug in openears? if so is there any way to correct this?
Any help is appreciated in advance.Thank you.

Comment: I have been looking for a library like that for awhile, downloading to see now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Using OpenEars In Your App](http://www.politepix.com/openears/yourapp)

There's a `corpus.txt` file in your example which allows it to recognize only:

GO

FORWARD

BACKWARD

LEFT

RIGHT

START

STOP

TURN

You can add other words or even phrases though.

Comment: OpenEars developer here. This is 100% correct -- the sample application has a fixed vocabulary and the docs explain how to create a custom vocabulary for your application. Recognizing any arbitrary statement isn't a thing that is currently possible to do in a framework that runs offline on a handheld device given the CPU/memory resources available (technically, the online large vocabulary recognition services also have a limited vocabulary; the limit is just a whole lot bigger). There's also some discussion in the docs and in the forums about what vocabulary sizes are workable offline.

Comment: @GrahamBell: static/dynamic is a matter of linking and iOS (i think) you can only link static libraries. From a functionality view it is very _dynamic_ :) ZXing for example is also static but that doesn't mean it can only recognize a certain set of QR codes.

Comment: @Halle thanks for the info, and i need to ask one more thing that is OpenEars is a free license or we need to buy it so as to use it in our application?

Comment: Hi Graham, OpenEars is free to use in your app -- read the license and the FAQ so you can be an informed developer. You can ask any followup questions at the OpenEars forums.